# How to get name of all report images in stimulsoft?

Tags: c#, .net, stimulsoft

I use  `Stireport` class in my project in order to generate some specific report photos by this.

```
report.Render(false);
string location = @"c:\Reports\test_report.jpg"
report.ExportDocument(StiExportFormat.ImageJpeg, location);
```

When my report is more than one page, first report image is saved with the name 'test_report' and other images are saved with other names. for example the second report image is saved with the name 'test_rep002' and the name of third image is 'test_rep003'.
Now I want to get name of all of my report images after `ExportDocument` method.
Note: I get `report.RenderedPages`  collections but unfortunately I can't get any conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count of pages from the RenderedPages collection.
The first name of the image will be as you set and all other will have 002, 003, 004 and so on.